# CSS Sprite for Submit Button not working (In Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, css, css-sprites

I'm having trouble getting my CSS sprite effect to work in my rails app, not sure why because I don't totally understand the concept.

Heres my submit button code:

```
<%= f.submit '', :class => 'submitpost'%>
```

and the CSS behind it:

```
.submitpost {
border: none;
height: 40px;
width: 145px;
background: url('sharebutton_up.jpg') 0 0;
}
 .submitpost:hover {
cursor:pointer;
height: 40px;
width: 145px;
background: url('sharebutton_down.jpg') 0 -40px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

background: url('sharebutton_down.jpg') 0 -40px;

I think you should remove -40px since you have changed the images from sharebutton_up to sharebutton_down already